# StorageItemQueryResult.ContentsChanged event not fired

Tags: uwp, windows-10, file-watcher

I want to monitor folder for recursive changes.
I use this code:

```
public async void StartMonitor(string folderPath)
{
    StorageFolder storageFolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(folderPath);
    QueryOptions queryOptions = new QueryOptions();
    queryOptions.FolderDepth = FolderDepth.Deep;
    StorageItemQueryResult query = storageFolder.CreateItemQueryWithOptions(queryOptions);
    query.ContentsChanged += QueryContentsChanged;
    await query.GetItemsAsync();
}

private void QueryContentsChanged(IStorageQueryResultBase sender, object args)
{
    //to do
}
```

Event is fired once after StatMonitor executes. But then when I create file or folder in this directory, event is not fired. How can I get this event firing?

Comment: Any updates about this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query object was going out of scope. I made the query object a private class field and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the document - [StorageFolderQueryResult.ContentsChanged Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.search.storagefolderqueryresult.contentschanged?view=winrt-22000), it mentions that you need to call the [StorageFileQueryResult.GetFilesAsync Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.search.storagefilequeryresult.getfilesasync?view=winrt-22000#windows-storage-search-storagefilequeryresult-getfilesasync(system-uint32-system-uint32)) for at least once to make the event work. So please try to call the GetFilesAsync method first before you handle the ContentsChanged event.

Comment: Thank you, Roy. I found my error. The query object was going out of scope. I made the query object a private class field and it works.

Comment: @N.Saw Glad to hear that. If you have found your issue. Please post it here as answer and mark it.